# HTMLbody to keep cell format

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script sending out HTML formatted emails to the list of recipients:

```
        <!-- Greeting section START -->
 <td width="100%" valign="top">
 <h1 style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 26px; margin: 0;">Hi there,</h1>
 <p style="margin: 0;">&nbsp;<br />Please provide the weekly status report by Monday, CoB: <br />&nbsp;</p>
 <p style="margin: 0;">
  <?= project ?> 
  <br />&nbsp;</p>
 <p style="margin: 0;"> Should you have any questions or experience difficulties, reach out to me.<br />&nbsp;</p>
<h1 style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 28px; margin: 0;">Best regards,</h1>
<h1 style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0;">PMO Team</h1>
</td>
                                    <!-- Greeting section END -->
```

The     reference in the code takes data from respective column ( htmlBody.project = row[3]) :

```
function sendEmailForm() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mail_template'); 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("T_TEST");
 var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 70; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    {
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
     if (emailAddress.match('@')  === null){
       continue;  // skip this iteration of the loop and go to the next one
    };
    var ccEmailAddress = row[1]
   // var body = row[3]; // Second column
    var subject = row[2];
   htmlBody.project = row[3];
    //htmlBody.survey = row[10];
   var message = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();
    //var body = email_html;
    var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
    Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
    Logger.log(aliases[1])
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody : message, cc: ccEmailAddress,'from': aliases[1]});
  }
  }
}
```

However, data in those cells are organized in paragraphs, e.g.:
Project 1
Project 2
Project 3

What I actually get in the emails is: Project 1 Project 2 Project 3

Is there any way to keep cell format in the emails? Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `sendEmailForm()` as follows.

##### From:

```
htmlBody.project = row[3];
```

##### To:

```
htmlBody.project = row[3].replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

And also, please modify the HTML as follows.

##### From:

```
<?= project ?>
```

##### To:

```
<?!= project ?>
```

- By the above modification, `Project 1\nProject 2\nProject 3` in a cell is converted to `Project 1<br>Project 2<br>Project 3` and this HTML is put using `<?!= project ?>`.

#### Reference:

- [Force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets)